# Number of comparisons in duplicates finding algorithm

Tags: algorithm, list, search

Let's suppose we have a sorted list containing N elements. I have read in a textbook that an algorithm which determines if this list has duplicates must perform at least `n-1`comparisons (that means `n-1` is a lower bound of the number of comparisons). I don't understand this because let's say the 1st and 2nd elements are duplicates, then the algorithm would simply return 'yes' after performing exactly one comparison. What do I get wrong? is there any simple proof of the `n-1` lower bound?

Comment: You possibly read that it needs `n-1` comparisons to determine the *opposite*, that all elements are unique. Because yes, if it finds that the first 2 elements are equal, then it need not go further.

Comment: The book says that `n-1` is a lower bound of the number of comparisons, if I understand it right, this means that in the worst case (where all elements are distinct), `n-1` comparisons are needed, all other cases should be then bigger than `n-1` and not smaller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When talking about complexity, you never consider only one input, otherwise there would always be some `O(1)` algorithm returning the expected answer.
An algorithm is supposed to work whatever the given input is (according to the specifications).

So for you, `n-1` is the lower bound on the worst case complexity for any algorithm (based on comparison), i.e. for any algorithm you can find one input for which it needs at least `n-1` comparisons.

Comment: What I'm confusing is the following: every case better than the worst case should have less comparisons than the worst case, which is true if we consider `n-1`comparisons as a worst case scenario (every element of the list is distinct), but if `n-1` is a lower bound of the set of all comparisons, this means every other case should be more than `n-1` comparisons, which is confusing me.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably confusing the two terms "lower bound" and "worst/best case".

The order of input determines the worst/best case, so, the lower bound or "big omega" can be said as "n-1" for the worst case and "1" for the best case.

But generally, the time complexity is determined for the worst cases.

Comment: Isn't `n-1` the lower bound of the set of all comparisons? that means it represents the smallest number of comparisons in the set of all numbers of comparisons, but at the same time it represents the biggest number of comparisons because it occurs only in the worst case, which I find confusing

Comment: You're right, the lower bound represents the **at least** time for _any_ possible order of inputs. However, it is not contradictory to say that the _worst-case_ running time is Ω(n-1), since there exists an input that causes the algorithm to take Ω(n-1) time.
So, in general, if you say that the algorithm takes Ω(n-1) time, it would mean for any possible order of input.